# pow with rbenv doesn't load the correct ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, rack-pow

Pow works fine with ruby 2.0.0, but when I want to use 1.9.3, pow doesn't load the correct ruby version (ruby-version file is exist with correct ruby version).

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
```

Comment: Did you restart pow after adding the `.ruby-version` file? Is the app loading the right ruby version if you start the console (`rails c`)?

Comment: rails console, and rails server or puma works fine, I restarted, but not helped

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I solved it by adding this line to my `~/.powconfig`:

`export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH`

I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a .ruby-version on your home directory delete it, it basically overrides the .ruby-version you have on your application path.

```
rm -rf ~/.ruby-version
```

This is a bug I encountered when I used pow.cx, .zsh, and rbenv